# JavaFX TableView content disappears on scrolling

Tags: tableview, javafx-2

I managed to create a `TableView` with specific columns assigned to a datamodel-class. The program can parse a csv file into it and shows everything correctly in the table. Scrolling isnt a problem at this stage.

Then I want to select specific rows and send them to another table. Which works as well. But when I start scrolling in table1 again the content outside the visual area is disappeared.

I dont really understand what happened here because I didn't changed anything for table1. Both lists are using Order as datamodel... perhaps this is a problem? Here is the code which sends the rows to table2:

```
if(init) { //init is true
    ObservableList<TableColumn<Order, ?>> header = table1.getColumns();
    table2.getColumns().addAll(header);
    table2.setItems(table2Observable);
    init = false;
}

table2Observable.addAll(table1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
table2.setItems(table2Observable);
```

Comment: Try using new columns for the second table

Comment: once i got a same problem but not with csv....i think it would be because of looping issue or null pointers

Answer (score 0):

if order is your bean class then override the hashcode() and equals() method properly. This is occurring because of the duplicate object. It worked for me.